# Changes to about:config on Firefox on all computer users

Tags: linux, firefox, linux-mint

I have a system (Linux Mint) with multiple users and I want them to have the same about:config values and parameters. If I change about:config in one user, will it be reflected to the other users' Firefox too or not? If not, is there an automated way (like a plugin or a script) that would enable me to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: They are usually stored in `~/.mozilla/firefox/*/prefs.js` as a "delta", meaning only non-default values are stored there.

Comment: So do the changes I made in one account (for example, I use X to tinker with about:config) will also be reflected into Y's when Y uses Firefox? Or does the * in `~/.mozilla/firefox/*/prefs.js` stand for users?

Comment: @Carlo The `~` character represents home directory of the current user and the `*` has to be replaced by the profile directory name. Every user has his own set of profiles. Probably you can try to write a script which would copy profile setting to a shared `profile.js` when closing Firefox and retrieve the shared `profile.js` when starting Firefox.

Comment: @Pabouk oh yes. Sorry for overlooking that one. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to write as an answer what came up in comments :

Firefox stores its preferences (a.k.a. about:config screen parameters) in a file named prefs.js stored in each user home directory, in `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile_id>/prefs.js` where `~` represents the current user directory and `<profile_id>` is a random generated  string of about 12 characters.

This file is stored as a 'Delta' which means only parameters that differ from default configuration will be there. i.e. if default config is :

```
a: 1
b: 1
c: 0
```

And your configuration is :

```
a: 1
b: 0
c: 0
```

`prefs.js` will look like :

```
b:0
```

To do what you want, you have to either copy a 'default' configuration file to the user's when he logs (via its  `~/.profile` file for example) or simply replace the file with a symbolic link to a default one. (which would be read-only for users and read-write for admin, still an example)

Hope that helps.